# Как вставить в TextView изображение, имея http-ссылку на него?

Tags: android, android-textview

Требуется помимо текста добавлять в один и тот же TextView изображения, имея http-ссылки на эти изображения. Как реализовать?
Желательно с возможностью задания размера (масштаба) изображения.

Comment: А зачем? Чем не подходит ImageView?

Comment: Я заранее не знаю сколько будет изображений, предлагаете динамически создавать ImageView?

Comment: При этом нужно, чтобы текст был вперемешку с изображениями, т.е. потом опять динамически добавлять новые TextView надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `SpannableString` для совмещение текста с изображениями.
Тут показан пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177667/2667883

Comment: Добавить изображение из ресурсов получилось. Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher); А как можно запилить то же самое, имея только URI-ссылку на изображение?

Comment: Предварительно их нужно загрузить, к примеру через библиотеку Universal-Image-Loader или Picasso. После чего добавить в текст.